# No music contents on iPhone after synchronization

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

Every time I synchronize my iPhone with iTunes on my computer, for example, when I want to add new music to my iPhone, I suddenly lose all my music on the iPhone.

I recently wanted to add a new album to my iPhone. So I plugged it in via USB, checked the album for synchronization in iTunes and started synchronization. After a while it finished and said "Synchronization done. You can disconnect your iPhone now blah blah…".

But when I looked at my iPhone and opened the iPod app, it says: "No contents". How is this possible? In iTunes there is an overview telling you how much space is full and what the space is used for. There I see 4,5 GB for Apps, 7 GB for music and some space for other stuff. On my iPhone I can check the space too, and there it also says that there should be the 7 GB of music, but the iPod app doesn't show any contents.

I also tried to restore my iPhone multiple times with different back-ups. It works until I sychnronize my iPhone the next time. Another strange thing is that restoring my iPhone isn't easy at all. It often aborts, showing random error messages (6,9,14). This is really annoying and I'm about to throw my iPhone against a wall.

Has anyone had similar problems and found a solution?

iPhone:

- iPhone 4 (32 GB)
- iOS 4.3.5
- no jailbreak

PC:

- iTunes 10.4.0.80
- Windows 7 64

Comment: Too bad that there is so few activity on apple.stackexchange...

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be your problem: Windows 7 64

If you can, try to sync your phone from a 32 bit machine. [Since](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3189711?start=0&tstart=0) the [dawn](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/ipod-sync-problem-windows-7-64bit/ed96dab8-9dd7-4deb-b498-37a4905ef91f) of the iPhone Apple hasn't played nicely with 64 bit flavors of Windows. [This fellow](http://stefanhendriks.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/windows-7-64bit-and-itunes-9-02-sync-problems/) says there's a [HotFix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976972) from MSFT to fix the issue.